# How to keep at least one file while looping in a directory?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am doing slice removal of images in folders, but I have to keep at least one image in each foder. I want to modify my code so that at least one image is left in each folder.

The current code is:

```py
count = []
folder_path = "/home/idu/Desktop/COV19D/train-seg3/covid"
# Change this directory to the directory where you need to do preprocessing for images
# Inside the directory must folder(s), which have the images inside them
for fldr in os.listdir(folder_path):
    sub_folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, fldr)
    for filee in os.listdir(sub_folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(sub_folder_path, filee)
        img = cv2.imread(file_path, 0)
        count = np.count_nonzero(
            img
        )  # Counting number of bright pixels in the binarized slices
        # print(count)
        if count > 1500:
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2)
            img = array_to_img(img)
            # Replace images with the image that includes ROI
            img.save(str(file_path), "JPEG")
            # print('saved')
        else:
            # Remove non-representative slices
            os.remove(str(file_path))
            # print('removed')
            # Check that there is at least one slice left
        if not os.listdir(str(sub_folder_path)):
            print(str(sub_folder_path), "Directory is empty")
        count = []
```

The above code only informs me if a directory is left empty after images removal. I would like to modify the code so that at least one image is left. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of how many files are in the directory and how many you’ve removed:

```py
for fldr in os.listdir(folder_path):
    sub_folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, fldr)
    if os.path.isdir(sub_folder_path): # check what's a dir
        directory = os.listdir(sub_folder_path)
        files_left = len(directory)  # get initial count
        for filee in directory:
            file_path = os.path.join(sub_folder_path, filee)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path): # check what's a file
                img = cv2.imread(file_path, 0)
                count = np.count_nonzero(img)
                if count > 1500:
                    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2)
                    img = array_to_img(img)
                    img.save(file_path, "JPEG")
                else:
                    if files_left > 1:  # check if you should remove
                        os.remove(file_path)
                        files_left -= 1
                if not os.listdir(sub_folder_path):
                    print(sub_folder_path, "Directory is empty")
```

Also, you’re calling `str` on strings, which is unnecessary.

As @theherk pointed out though, this doesn't work recursively:

```
$ tree files/
files
├── a
│   ├── aa
│   │   ├── aaf1.png
│   │   └── aaf2.png
│   ├── ab
│   │   ├── abf1.png
│   │   └── abf2.png
│   ├── af1.png
│   └── af2.png
├── b
│   ├── bf1.png
│   └── bf2.png
└── f1.png
$ python3 keepOne.py files/
$ tree files/
files
├── a
│   ├── aa
│   │   ├── aaf1.png
│   │   └── aaf2.png
│   └── ab
│       ├── abf1.png
│       └── abf2.png
├── b
│   └── bf1.png
└── f1.png
```

If you want to remove the files recursively, you should definitely use `os.walk`:

```py
for dir_path, _, directory in os.walk(top_path):
    files_left = len(directory)  # get initial count
    for file_name in directory:
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        img = cv2.imread(file_path, 0)
        count = np.count_nonzero(img)
        if count > 1500:
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2)
            img = array_to_img(img)
            img.save(file_path, "JPEG")
        else:
            if files_left > 1:  # check if you should remove
                os.remove(file_path)
                files_left -= 1
```

Which results in:

```
$ tree files
files
├── a
│   ├── aa
│   │   ├── aaf1.png
│   │   └── aaf2.png
│   ├── ab
│   │   ├── abf1.png
│   │   └── abf2.png
│   ├── af1.png
│   └── af2.png
├── b
│   ├── bf1.png
│   └── bf2.png
└── f1.png
$ python3 keepFile.py files
$ tree files
files
├── a
│   ├── aa
│   │   └── aaf1.png
│   ├── ab
│   │   └── abf1.png
│   └── af1.png
├── b
│   └── bf1.png
└── f1.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for this task. It also makes use of [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and [os.remove](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove).

In this contrived example, we have a folder with nested directories, each containing one or more png files.

```
ᐅ exa -T -L 4 ./files
./files
├── a
│  ├── aa
│  │  ├── aaf1.png
│  │  └── aaf2.png
│  ├── ab
│  │  ├── abf1.png
│  │  └── abf2.png
│  ├── af1.png
│  └── af2.png
├── b
│  ├── bf1.png
│  └── bf2.png
└── f1.png
```

We iterate over these, and for each directory of files iterate of the slice of all but one file, deleting the files in the given slice.

```py
import os

for path, _, files in os.walk("./files"):
    for f in files[1:]:
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
```

Then we are left with directory contents:

```
ᐅ exa -T -L 4 ./files
./files
├── a
│  ├── aa
│  │  └── aaf2.png
│  ├── ab
│  │  └── abf2.png
│  └── af2.png
├── b
│  └── bf2.png
└── f1.png
```